# UICollectionView willDisplayCell delegate method?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

Anyway to hack into UICollectionView to call willDisplayCell delegate method, when displaying cell?

I need this for lazy loading, and I'm doing it nice with UITableView, but officially UICollectionView doesn't have that kind of delegate method.

So, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Just of curiosity: Why is dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: not sufficient? Isn't that already lazy loading? I thought that cell will be displayed right after this method.

Comment: @Masa it's "sort of" lazy loading, but imagine you had a fullscreen image at 2208x1242 pixels and you wanted to only allow one http connection to the visible image.  `cellForItemAtIndexPath` would fire multiple times, it's basically prefetching, not lazy loading. FYI: this delegate is available in ios8 https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FYI, This has been added to the API for iOS 8:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

Comment: Official documentation is extremely confusing. Look what they say under discussion

`Discussion
The collection view calls this method before adding a cell to its content. Use this method to detect cell additions, as opposed to monitoring the cell itself to see when it appears.`

Wait, what? So it's not notified on willDisplay?

Comment: This can be used to set up a cell before display on iOS 8+. It will not be called on iOS 7 and previous.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like this in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` (for lazy loading images):

- If my model has the image, just set the cell's image to it
- If the model does not have an image, kick of an async load
- When the load completes, the check if the original indexPath is still visible
- If so, call `cellForItemAtIndexPath` for the original indexPath. Since the image now exists in the model, the cell's image will now be set.

Looks like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PhotoCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
id imageItem = [self.photoSet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        ImageManager * listingImage = (ImageManager *)imageItem;
        if(listingImage.image){
            cell.image = listingImage.image;
        } else {
            [listingImage loadImage:^(UIImage *image) {
                [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if ([[collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] containsObject:indexPath]) {
                        [(PhotoCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] setImage:image];
                    }
                });
            }];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `SDWebImage` https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage for lazy loading. You can use this effectively with `UICollectionView`.

---

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

/*---------
----Other CollectiveView stuffs------
-----------------*/
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:YOUR_FILE_PATH  isDirectory:NO])
{
      imagView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:YOUR_FILE_PATH];
}
else
{
     UIActivityIndicatorView *act=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
     [imagView addSubview:act];
     act.center=CGPointMake(imagView.frame.size.width/2, imagView.frame.size.height/2);
     [act startAnimating];

     __weak typeof(UIImageView) *weakImgView = imagView; 
     [imagView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:REMOTE_FILE_PATH] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){
    for(UIView *dd in weakImgView.subviews)
    {
        if([dd isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]])
        {
            UIActivityIndicatorView *act=(UIActivityIndicatorView *)dd;
            [act stopAnimating];
            [act removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    NSString *extension=[YOUR_FILE_PATH pathExtension];

    [self saveImage:image withFileName:YOUR_FILE_PATH ofType:extension];
  }];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation when I need to know the index path of cell which is going to be displayed. Ended with `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Assumably, one is "didEndDisplaying", another is "willDisplayed".

Comment: Actually, it is totally different. willDisplayCell is triggered right before the Cell is rendered to appear on the screen. didEndDisplayingCell is triggered just the moment the cell disappear for the screen.That is to say that if you use didEndDiplayingCell, you can't make an infinite scroll by detecting on the last Cell, as the user would have to display it, and them to scroll up just enough for it to disappear in order for new elements to be loaded. Not really user friendly, right ?

Comment: i switched to methods like detecting if UIScrollView has hit the bottom